# Using conditional panels in Shiny, how can I make sure that they appear as soon as the slider in rendered?

Tags: r, slider, shiny

So far, I am solving this in involving a condition as follows:

```
      conditionalPanel("input.sliderOne != 0",
      h5("this is a test"),
      sliderInput("sliderTwo", label = "Test", min = 0, max = 4, value = 0, step = 1))
```

I was wondering if there is a more general way of doing this since my condition depends on the default value I set in the silder Input. It would be nice if there is something like "as soon as the slider (sliderOne) is rendered, the panel appears, independently of the default value.

Comment: Theoretically, you could render both elements on the server side using `renderUI` and you can get what you want.